# Scala: Compilation error: Cannot resolve overloaded method

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, java-8, playframework, compiler-errors

I have imported to Intellij a Play/Scala project with [the following method](https://github.com/manuelbernhardt/reactive-web-applications/blob/master/CH07/app/controllers/Application.scala) that gets a compilation error for a reason which I do not understand. Any ideas what is wrong here?

I am using Java 8 and Scala 2.11.6.

```
  def fetchUser(id: Long): Option[UserRecord] =
    Cache.getAs[UserRecord](id.toString).map { user =>
      Some(user)
    } getOrElse {
      DB.withConnection { connection =>
        val sql = DSL.using(connection, SQLDialect.POSTGRES_9_4)
        val user = Option(sql.selectFrom[UserRecord](USER).where(USER.ID.equal(id)).fetchOne())
        user.foreach { u =>
          Cache.set(u.getId.toString, u)
        }
        user
      }
    }
```

The compilation error is on the call to the `withConnection` method. The error is: `Cannot resolve overloaded method 'withConnection'`.

When I try to jump to the implementation of the `withConnection` method, the compiler suggests two possible methods in the `play.api.db.DB (2.4.3)` class:

```
  /**
   * Execute a block of code, providing a JDBC connection. The connection is
   * automatically released.
   *
   * @param name The datasource name.
   * @param autocommit when `true`, sets this connection to auto-commit
   * @param block Code block to execute.
   */
  def withConnection[A](name: String = "default", autocommit: Boolean = true)(block: Connection => A)(implicit app: Application): A =
    db.database(name).withConnection(autocommit)(block)

  /**
   * Execute a block of code, providing a JDBC connection. The connection and all created statements are
   * automatically released.
   *
   * @param block Code block to execute.
   */
  def withConnection[A](block: Connection => A)(implicit app: Application): A =
    db.database("default").withConnection(block)
```

Comment: Did you modify the source at all? If not, consider reporting this as an issue on the GitHub repo. I would start by checking everything is compatible. You mention scala `2.11.6` but the `sbt` specifies `2.11.7` https://github.com/manuelbernhardt/reactive-web-applications/commit/d173adabcf4ab062ab858a60a9146b620f1ae6bf

Comment: The compiler complains because it can't figure out which method to call. You might try,  `DB.withConnection(name="default", autocommit="true") {...}` in case it's the default parameters messing with things. Could also be that it can't resolve the implicit `Application`

Comment: Both versions of Scala did not solve this problem. I changed to 2.11.6 because projects of other chapters had a problem with 2.11.7. When things work as expected, which method is picked by the compiler when `withConnection` as in the original code which I posted, the method with 2 or 3 parameter lists? I tried to add a parameter list with two parameters as you suggested (I think you can simply use an explicit empty list instead), but I still have this problem.

Comment: P.S. If you look at the equivalent controllers/Application.scala file in the CH08 project in the Github repo, there is a very similar method call in that code. When I imported the CH08 project into Intellij, the IDE does NOT show a compilation error on the method call. (I had to downgrade the SBT version at CH08 for the compilation to work, so I did the same also at CH07). In CH08, the compiler had no problem to pick one of the methods (I think in this case it picks the one with only 2 parameter lists).

Comment: It might be one of those strange cases (a.k.a. bugs) of inability of the IDE to recognize code changes. I have had such incidents numerous times in Intellij and Eclipse, not only but mainly when I import a new project, or when I change the version of some dependencies of a working project. And Stackoverflow is full of such questions and the voodoo solutions that work for some people but not for others. I did try "invalidate caches & restart" but there is no change.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler should find

```scala
def withConnection[A](block: Connection => A)(implicit app: Application): A =
    db.database("default").withConnection(block)
```

because that matches the call

```scala
DB.withConnection { ... }
```

which is the same as

```scala
DB.withConnection( block = { ... })
```

as long as it can find the implicit `Application`. I don't know where this implicit `Application` exists but since this is from a sample project to a book I assume it exists somewhere and has worked in the past.

You've posted three questions pertaining to build errors about this project. Please don't post a new question every time you run into a build error for this project. That's not the point of SO. These questions are best aimed at the maintainer of the project itself, ie. the author on the issues page of the GitHub repo.

Now it doesn't look like this project is maintained. It's an old project. You're very likely to run into issues where things are broken because of outdated versions. Consider asking ONE question about building an old play project instead.

Comment: @rapt while I agree with your disagreement, I would like to note that your additional retort is uncalled for and entirely unhelpful. Ad Hominem attacks are absolutely not what StackOverflow is about, and this person took some time in an attempt to help you. Granted, posting on a forum is bound to not get you exactly what you want, and some ... interesting ... opinions, but any input should be considered a service, or just disregarded. If you want to complain, be constructive, and cite some sources. A great link for you both to read might be: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Cheers!